# why does my routing not working (/user/create)

Tags: node.js, routes

This is how I set up the routing:
I'm trying to render create page when the user access the url domain.com/user/create
but when I try, it redirects to my original .get("/") instead (.get("/create"))

My routes:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrCn4.png

My view folder structure:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9ngF.png

My app.js
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfXIr.png

Edited (With new finding and including codes instead of images)
I found out this was because I have the router with :email parameter.

```
router.get("/:email", userController.GetUserByParam, (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.data);
    res.render("user", { userList: req.data, date: req.date });
    //res.send(req.data);
    });
```

I just don't understand why that interfere with my create routing?

```
router.get("/create", (req, res) => {
    //res.send("Test");
    res.render("Create");
    });
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Answer (score -1):

remove "/" before create and also add your controller after create.
if you want add data in database you need to use post

```
router.post("create",controller.something(req,res)=>{
  res.render("created")
})
```

Comment: I'm using get because I just wanna render the page for now. I removed the / and it's still not working.

Comment: see in your code you forget to add controller  after "create", controller.<----- here